# Dynamically address lookup in Django template

Tags: django, django-templates

- I have a form on Django template with 2 fields: POSTCODE and HOUSE_NUMBER.
  I have a address_find() method in the related view.
- I need the full address to be displayed when the user fills in these 2 fields without submitting the form. ( In other words, when user enters POSTCODE and HOUSE_NUMBER, before submitting I want to check the address with address_find() method and display the full address under the form)
- Is it possible to do that in Django templates? or do I need to submit the form to do that?
  Thanks.

Comment: You likely will need some JavaScript to pass the data to the function, and then render the result. But it would likely help if you show the current state of the view and template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution:

First need to add an endpoint in your Django views:

```
# views.py
from django.http import JsonResponse

def address_lookup(request):
    postcode = request.GET.get('postcode')
    house_number = request.GET.get('house_number')
    full_address = address_find(postcode, house_number)
    return JsonResponse({'full_address': full_address})
```

Then need to create a URL pattern for the new view:

```
# urls.py
from django.urls import path
from .views import address_lookup

urlpatterns = [
    # other patterns
    path('address_lookup/', address_lookup, name='address_lookup'),
]
```

Finally need to write JavaScript to handle form input:

```
<script>
    // Add event listeners to input fields
    document.getElementById('postcode').addEventListener('input', updateAddress);
    document.getElementById('house_number').addEventListener('input', updateAddress);

    function updateAddress() {
        // Get values from input fields
        var postcode = document.getElementById('postcode').value;
        var houseNumber = document.getElementById('house_number').value;

        // Make an Ajax request to the server
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('GET', '/address_lookup/?postcode=' + postcode + '&house_number=' + houseNumber, true);
        xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && xhr.status === 200) {
                // Update the displayed address
                document.getElementById('fullAddress').innerText = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText).full_address;
            }
        };
        xhr.send();
    }
</script>
```